# jquery move text like movie credits

Tags: jquery, html, css

Does anyone know a jquery plugin or css3 technique another easy way to move text elements, say 10 h1's inside a div from top to bottom of the div?

So

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <h1>Content</h1>
...
</div>
```

I want the h1's to slide continuously and that the div area is filled with h1's sliding downwards like movie credits.

I tried jquery cycle plugin but i cant get the second slide(h1) to start before the first one finishes his animation.

Here is the code:

```
$('.container').cycle({ 
    fx:      'scrollDown', 
    sync: 1, 
    timeout: 1000,
    speed: 6000,
    continuous: 1,
    cleartypeNoBg: true 
});
```

Also tried something like this:

```
$('.container').cycle({ 
    fx:      'custom', 
    sync: 1, 
    cssBefore: {  
    top:  0, 
    display: 'block' 
    }, 
    animIn:  { 
        top: 0 
    }, 
    animOut: {  
        top: 332 
    }, 
    cssAfter: {   
        display: 'none' 
    }, 
    delay: -1000  
    });
});
```

Comment: Just a small comment: The use of `<h1>` is not allowed this way. But you can just do something with jQuery animate. Have a look into that first.

Comment: @putvande, please explain? A `div` allows flow content, and `h1` is a flow element...

Comment: `<h1>` supposed to be used as a unique peace on the page, such as `Page Title` or maybe a `post title`, which is because of `SEO`, multiple `<h1>` tags are bad for `SEO`. Also, `h1` stabds for `header one` which is not semantic in this use case.`<h1>Google sees this text as more important</h1><p>… than this text</p>` .

Comment: If it is a HTML4 page, you can only use 1 `h1` tag. If it is a HTML5 page you can use more than 1 `h1`, but not more than 1 per section.

Comment: http://www.interspire.com/content/2005/12/07/google-seo-basics-for-beginners/

Comment: thanks for the info, i changed the h1 into paragraphs.

Comment: OK, for SEO purposes, sure, and I see a lot of people saying only one H1 per section, but I don't see this anywhere in the HTML spec. Is this a real constraint or just an SEO/document semantic practice?

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you want....

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="fancy_h1_wrap">
        <h1>Content</h1>
        <h1>Content</h1>
        <h1>Content</h1>
        <h1>Content</h1>
        <h1>Content</h1>
        <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
function fun(){
    $('#fancy_h1_wrap').css('top', '');
    $('#fancy_h1_wrap').animate({top:"-100%"}, 5000, fun);

}

fun();
```

css

```
#container 
{
    overflow:hidden;

}

#fancy_h1_wrap
{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
}
```

[WORKING JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qc8sc/4)

Comment: thanks for the help, now i need just the part where it loops continuously, this one stops after it is done once. I would like it to loop so that immediately when there is space the h1's appear immediately and continue to scroll. So infinite scrolling and no empty space in the container as in it should look like there is always a new h1 immediately there.

Comment: sigh i wish the WHATWG would bring us back the old school marquee/blink element. this is such a commonly needed thing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element

Comment: @cliffbarnes Geocities in the house!

Comment: Unfortunately that stuff never worked right cuz MS MZ were in a browser war. That might be something to taking that up with the WHATWG.  But yeah, :P, Geocities, MySpace, and CGI-Gateway in tha house! lol